# What is meaning of this symbol / notation in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, terminology

I am trying questions of assignment of an institute in which I don't study.

> There is a question in which $\Omega$ is a bounded region and f$\in C(\bar\Omega) \cap H(\Omega)$.

I have no idea on what is meant by $C(\bar\Omega) $ although I know that  $H(\Omega)$ is set of all holomorphic functions on set $\Omega$ .  I tried searching on google but could not found it's meaning although some links going to mathstackexchage has vaguely similar terms ( but only vaguely) .

So, can anyone please tell meaning of this notation?

Thank you.

Comment: $C(\bar\Omega)$ are the *continuous* functions on $\bar\Omega$.

Comment: Holomorphic in $\Omega$, and continuous on the closure of $\Omega$.

Comment: It is the space of continuous functions on $\overline {\Omega}$.

Comment: $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is the set of continuous functions on $\overline{\Omega}$, which is the closure of the region $\Omega$. Thus the intersection consists in functions that are contiunous on the boundary and holomorphic on the interior of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a bar over a set often means taking the closure. And the $C$ means the set of continuous (complex-valued) functions on the given set. So what you have is a symbol-heavy way to say that $f$ is continuous on the closure of $\Omega$ and holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Comment: To be pedantic, $C(\bar\Omega)$ and $H(\Omega)$ have no elements in common, as they are sets of functions with different domains. But writing around this issue to get at what we actually mean is going to be cumbersome, so we abuse the notation a bit. It's not really ambiguous, so we can get away with a bit of unpreciseness.